# help debug a php page

Tags: php, logging, visitor-statistic

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// Getting the information 
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
$page = "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}";
if(!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) $page .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$datetime = mktime(); 
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$remotehost = getHostByAddr($ipaddress);

// Create log line
$logline = $ipaddress . '|' . $referrer . '|' . $datetime . '|' . $useragent . '|' . $remotehost . '|' . $page . "\n"; 
echo $logline;
// Write to log file: 
//$logfile = 'logfile.txt';
$logfile = '/home/www/agro-dive.onlinewebshop.net/logfile.txt';

// Open the log file in "Append" mode 
if (!$handle = fopen($logfile, 'a+')) {
    die("Failed to open log file"); 
} 

// Write $logline to our logfile. 
if (fwrite($handle, $logline) == FALSE) {
    die("Failed to write to log file"); 
} 

fclose($handle);  

?>
```

if i try to open this php it gives me a server error

```
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.
```

and i have also tested it follow the steps [here](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=195), but it didn't produce any log message

Comment: Sounds like `path` problem. Are you sure, logfile.txt lies in the directory of the running script?

Comment: You are getting "Failed to open log file" or "Failed to write to log file" (or anything else) as response?

Comment: `$logfile = 'logfile.txt';` or `$logfile = '$logfile = 'logfile.txt';$logfile = '/home/www/agro-dive.onlinewebshop.net/logfile.txt';` does not make any differnece, i do have an empty "logfile.txt" file in my dir

Comment: "A server error" is too broad, please specify the *exact* error message you get. Adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` as first line of your script could be helpful (and removing the @ before gethostbyaddr would as well). BTW Where does your `iff` function come from? I don't see an include and AFAIK it's not a builtin PHP function or language construct.

Comment: I have modified the code but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't answer your question about debugging and logging but for what it's worth. Your error is on line 6.
Replace it by following:

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']))
    $page .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

Comment: Thanks to **wimvds** who identified my problem and **Bart Vangeneugden** who provided me a solution, my code was initially `$page .= iif(!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']), "?{$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']}", "");`

Answer (score 1):

"server error" means **"you have to look into servers error_log for the particular error message"**.

Debugging stands for reading error messages, not watching the code nor guessing.

Comment: thanks for the advice, but the desperate situation is i got `Not Found

The requested URL /logs/error/agro-dive-imports.onlinewebshop.net.log was not found on this server.` from the control panel

Comment: @Miranda it seems you have to ask your ISP support or consult the docs to locate an error log.

Answer (score 0):

BobDcoder here! 2019 update

While this is marked as solved/accepted/whatever, the answer appears to be the wrong fix according to the documentation. Many newbies and seasoned coders alike believe this to be a ternary if statement. ( however you spell ternary,lol.) but the original poster (op) states differently!

while I could be wrong I think the problem is:

```
$page = "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}"; 
$page .= iif(!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']), "?{$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']}", "");
```

(which  **$page** is an append to on the second line of code.)

many newbies and seasoned coders alike believe this to be a ternary if statement. ( however you spell ternary,lol.)

In the original documentation, the OP states that this is a function call. https://www.go4expert.com/articles/track-visitors-using-php-t195/

To quote the OP in the documentation........
"Note: I used a function in the above example called iif(). You can get this function at http://www.phpit.net/code/iif-function."

Sadly the link to the iif() function is dead, so maybe someone has the old code for this function and can post it here or at some other repository.

While the other correction above may allow the code to test true or false and fall through and process the rest of the code, I think the OP may have used it "iif() for other purposes as a function (bad programing choice of a function call).

Answer (score -1):

```
// Write to log file: 
//$logfile = 'logfile.txt';
$logfile = 'log.log';
```

where log.log is your log file